# Java DataOutputStream doesn't throw IOException on disconnect

Tags: java, ioexception, dataoutputstream

`DataOutputStream` doesn't throw an `IOException` when I plug my cable out, what's wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

```
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    try {
        mDataOutputStream.writeUTF(message);
        mDataOutputStream.flush();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        close();
    }
}
```

As soon as I plug the cable back in, the data is still sent to the server.

Comment: Have you waited long enough to see if it would eventually time out?

Comment: Yes, I've waited over more than an hour for a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

TCP connection are designed to cope with short term failures gracefully, and transparently where possible.  This means when the connection is lost for short period e.g. less than 3 minutes, the connection should re-establish itself transparently.  Even if the connection has timed out you will not know asynchronously, it may be the next read or write which fails.